# Apache Shiro: PermissionsQuery seems to return nothing

Tags: jdbc, shiro

In `shiro.ini` I declare the following SQL-queries:

```
jdbcRealm.authenticationQuery = SELECT password FROM Person WHERE email = ?
jdbcRealm.userRolesQuery = SELECT id FROM SecurityRole WHERE id = (SELECT securityRole_id FROM Person WHERE email = ?)
jdbcRealm.permissionsQuery = SELECT action FROM SecurityPermission WHERE id = (SELECT permissions_id FROM securityrole_securitypermission WHERE securityrole_id = ?)
```

When I replace the `?` in the last query with `1` an run it on the db it returns the expected result: `rest:*`
But `SecurityUtils.getSubject().isPermitted(new WildcardPermission("rest"));` will return `false` although the logged in user has an assigned role with id = 1, `securityrole_securitypermission` has an entry with ids 1 and 1, and `securitypermission` with id 1 has `action` = "rest:*".

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`jdbcRealm.permissionsLookupEnabled = true` did the job. ;)